# Como elegir JAVA al crear un proyecto en lugar de Kotlin en Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: java, android, kotlin, studio

Uso **Android Studio Flamingo**, JDK 17.0.8, AGP 8.0.2.

Al crear un nuevo proyecto no sale el desplegable que salía en otras versiones para elegir entre JAVA y KOTLIN, la primera MainActivity ya sale creada en kotlin y aunque puedo crear otras Activity, Clases, etc. en Java tengo que indicarlo al añadirlas y no logro que Java sea el lenguaje por defecto en todo el proyecto.

En **File > New Projects Setup -> Settings for new Projects** no hay opción para hacerlo.

En **File > Settings > Languages & Framework** tampoco o al menos yo no lo encuentro.

Si intento traducir desde Kotlin a Java no sale esa opción en el target de **Tools -> Kotlin-> Decompile -> Show Kotlin bytecode**
y la opción **Tools -> Kotlin -> Decompile to Java** sale deshabilitada.

¿Alguien sabe cómo poner Java como lenguaje de inicio? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dejas por default la selección del activity es cuando no te deja seleccionar el lenguaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando elijes otro tipo de Activity la selección de lenguaje aparece con normalidad. Agrego capturas de pantalla con la version flamingo, con los pasos que estoy ejecutando donde se muestra con normalidad:

Creo un proyecto nuevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono un Activity vacío para el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente ventana selecciono el lenguaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el proyecto fue creado con Java desde el inicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver aún es posible la selección de lenguaje al iniciar un proyecto cuando cambias el tipo de Activity inicial.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, efectivamente así ocurre al iniciar con un tipo de Activity que no sea el que viene por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Al seleccionar tu proyecto **es necesario selecciones "Empty Views Activity"**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después ya podrás seleccionar el lenguaje, **<kbd>Kotlin</kbd>** o **<kbd>Java</kbd>**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Google está tratando tácitamente a usar el lenguaje <kbd>Kotlin</kbd>, incluso actualmente hay mecanismos, clases, métodos que son obsoletos en Java y la única opción para poder actualizarlos es usando el lenguaje <kbd>Kotlin</kbd>.**

Te sugiero revisar:

[Enfoque de prioridad de **Kotlin** en Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first?hl=es-419)

> **En Google I/O 2019, anunciamos que el desarrollo de Android estaría cada vez más orientado a <kbd>Kotlin</kbd>.** Seguimos manteniendo ese
> compromiso. Kotlin es un lenguaje de programación expresivo y conciso
> que permite reducir los errores de código comunes y se integra
> fácilmente en las apps existentes. Si quieres crear una app para
> Android, te recomendamos que comiences con <kbd>Kotlin</kbd> a fin de aprovechar
> sus mejores funciones.